# IntelliJ to use scalafmt reformat code during Git check in

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When I check in my code to Git, there is an option in IntelliJ to reformat the code before checking in. I want to use `scalafmt` instead of IntelliJ standard Scala formatter to format my code before it is committed. Is there such option? Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get on top of this @thilm ?

Comment: I didn’t follow up with this as I prefer to use manual formatting ie I format the code before I check in

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable scalafmt formatter in IntelliJ options instead of IntelliJ formatter.

This way scalafmt will be applied whenever formatting occurs (manually or at commit).

Comment: i set it the formatter to Scalafmt in Editor > Code Style > Scala

Comment: Latest version of IntelliJ? I can't check right now but pretty sure it's working with latest version at least.

Comment: I'm definitely in the latest version (2022.2.1), and this is not working. Although in the 'Editor > Code Style > Scala' and then Scalafmt tab, there is the option 'Use IntelliJ formatter for code range formatting' and I have that on - because if you turn it off you trigger a warning. I wonder if that's causing the override...